# How to add action event on a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm using a variable say **component** to iterate through a menu list in jQuery, where each item is assigned to **component** while iterating.

```
var component = $('select#load option');
```

where all choices are enclosed like this under `id="load":

```
<option>choice</option>
```

How can I attach an event like `dblclick` to all of these choices in the list, so that if I double click on one of the choices in the menu, it opens. I did this, but it didn't work:

```
component.dblclick(function(){
....
});
```

Comment: Im no expert at jQuery, but do believe you just attach it how you would on `$('select#load option')`

Comment: Not all browsers support mouse event on option element, chrome e.g doesn't. Anyway, by clicking option element, you are closing dropdown list if not a multiple select element. So using a double click seems quite out of the purpose here

Comment: it's not a dropdown. It's something like open dialog box, where i want to open a file after double clicking it.

Comment: hope there is a typo `component` not `components`

Comment: Did you not look at jQuery's documentation on adding events. Also not all browsers support click events on options. You would need to listen to the click on the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to do is something like this?

```js
$(function(){
    
  var $opt = $('select#test option');
    
  $opt.on('dblclick',function(){
    
      alert($(this).val());
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id='test'size='3'>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It is not going to work with IE since it does not support clicks on options.